# Add css and js only for other "page--node--x.tpl.php" in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

i would like to have other template for only page (in my case node/348), so i write that i must create other

```
 page--node--348.tpl.php
```

but now how can add other external css and js file ? where ?

Maybe in template.php ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a hook_node_view in one of your custom module, then check the node id is 348 and inject your css and js like this :

```
function nameOfYourModule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->nid == 348) {
    $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => path_to_theme() . '/js/my_script.js',
      'group' => JS_THEME,
      'preprocess' => TRUE,
      'scope' => 'footer',
      'weight' => '999',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think for "custom module" ? maybe the template.php file ?

Comment: Drupal themes can only implement theme functions (which include template preprocess and process functions) or alter hooks. If you have never created a module it is a good time to start : https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7
All you need is a directory with the name of your module, and a .module and .info file with the name of your module. In your .module you will just have the function I described.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a condition in "template_preprocess_html()" function in your "template.php" as below:

```
<?php
    function THEME_NAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
      $arg = arg();
      $nid = 348;
      if ($arg[1] == $nid) {
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/my_style.css');
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/my_script.js');
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Using drupal_add_js and drupal_add_css is frowned upon in drupal >= 7.x, to the point it disappeared in drupal 8. The main reason is linked to how cache engines are saving pages. So please stop using it in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module CSS injector and JS to custom ONLY the node that you want:

https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector

about js, you can create a new js and custom with "id" and "class" of your node.
With css injector you can anable the changes only for the node that you want.

Comment: If the only purpose of adding this module is to add one js and css, better write the code yourself. The less modules installed the better on perfs.